# PICkit 3 not recognised by Computer

Tags: microchip, xc8

I got a completely new PICkit 3, MPLAB X on a MacBook Pro and the PIC16F1827. I set up a new project with the xc8 compiler and, to my knowledge set up everything correctly. Then I connected my PICkit and thought that it would start downloading and flashing a new firmware.

Instead it just flashed the STATUS LED red and nothing happened. I have power on the PICkit and the connection is active.

This is what I get, when trying to start a debugging session:[image]

I tried reinstalling MPLAB X and to switch the USB Cable, in case it was faulty. Any suggestions?

Comment: So what happens when you choose PICKit3 and click OK?

Comment: Nothing happens, the window closes and thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault was actually Apples System Integrity Protection, which prevented the installer from changing vital permissions of one installation folder. By now this has probably already been resolved in the new versions.

But in case anyone still needs it:

1. Reboot your mac into recovery mode.
2. Open the terminal.
3. Type `csrutil disable` #this disables the SIP on your machine
4. Reboot and install MPLAB X
5. Reboot into recovery again and reenable SIP (with `csrutil enable`)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a tool is detected, the serial number appears below its name. I believe your PICkit3 is not being detected. Do you have it connected directly to the USB port on you computer? Sometimes they don't get recognized when connecting through USB hubs.

Comment: I actually figured it out quiet a while ago, it had to do with macs System Integrity Protection, which prevented some library from loading. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you mind posting that as an answer?  Others may find it useful in the future.